# Spring with Thymeleaf, BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'user' available as request attribute

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have created a form using Thymeleaf and Spring and run into this issue.
I also read [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58016943/thymeleaf-spring-neither-bindingresult-nor-plain-target-object-for-bean-name) question but it didn't work for me

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>mz.painting</groupId>
    <artifactId>mz</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>M&amp;Z Painting</name>
    <description>Web Application for M&amp;Z </description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring5</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**Controller Update**

```
@Controller
 public class SavingUser{

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @GetMapping("/addUser")
    public String addUser(Model model){
        System.out.println("Adding User in registration page..");
        model.addAttribute("user", new Customer());
        return "service";

    }


    @PostMapping("/registerUser")
    public String userRegistration(@ModelAttribute Customer user, Model model){
        System.out.println("User in registration page..");
        model.addAttribute("user", user);
//        userRepository.save(user);
        return "redirect:/service";

    }
```

```
**Bean Class**
    Getters()
    Setters()
    toString()
```

**HTML Form**

```
    <div id="form">
        <form action="registerUser" th:action="@{/registerUser}"  
     th:object="${user}" method="POST">
            <br />
            <label>Your Name:</label><br />
            <input type="text" th:field="*{name}"  placeholder="" /><br>


            <label >Your Suburb</label><br />
            <input type="text"  th:field="*{suburb}"  placeholder="" /><br />

            <label>Email</label><br/>
            <input type="email" th:field="*{email}"  placeholder="" /><br />

            <label>Phone</label><br/>
            <input type="tel" th:field="*{phone}" placeholder="" /><br />

            <label>Please tell us how we can help</label><br />
            <textarea type="text" th:field="*{text}" rows="10" cols="40"></textarea><br />
            <div>
                <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"  /><br/><br/>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

**Full Error Message**

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.SpringInputGeneralFieldTagProcessor' (template: "index" - line 86, col 32)] with root cause
```

"index" - line 86, col 32)] in HTML Form is this ->

```
            <input type="text" th:field="*{name}"  placeholder="" /><br>
```

I also checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48359208/spring-thymeleaf-templateprocessingexception-in-springinputgeneralfieldtagproces) solution and it didn't work for me

**Update**
Terminal Page

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.1\bin\java.exe" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.1.2\lib\idea_rt.jar=49969:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.1.2\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath C:\Users\shuja\Desktop\mz\target\classes;C:\Users\shuja\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter\2.5.3\spring-boot-starter-2.5.3.jar;C:\Users\shuja\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\2.5.3\spring-boot-2.5.3.jar;C:\Users\shuja\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\5.3.9\spring-context-5.3.9.jar;C:\Users\shuja\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure\2.5.3\spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.5.3.jar;C:\Users\shuja\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-logging\2.5.3\spring-boot-starter-logging-2.5.3.jar;C:\Users\shuja\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-classic\1.2.4\logback-classic-1.2.4.jar;C:\Users\shuja\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-core\1.2.4\logback-core-1.2.4.jar;C:\Users\shuja\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-to-slf4j\2.14.1\log4j-to-slf4j-2.14.1.jar;C:\Users\shuja\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.14.1\log4j-api-2.14.1.jar;C:\Users\shuja\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jul-to-slf4j\1.7.32\jul-to-slf4j-1.7.32.jar;C:\Users\shuja\.m2\repository\jakarta\annotation\jakarta.annotation-api\1.3.5\jakarta.annotation-api-1.3.5.jar;C:\Users\shuja\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\5.3.9\spring-core-5.3.9.jar;C:\Users\shuja\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jcl\5.3.9\spring-jcl-5.3.9.jar;C:\Users\shuja\.m2\repository\org\yaml\snakeyaml\1.28\snakeyaml-1.28.jar;C:\Users\shuja\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-web\2.5.3\spring-boot-starter-web-2.5.3.jar;C:\Users\shuja\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-json\2.5.3\spring-boot-starter-json-2.5.3.jar;C:\Users\shuja\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.12.4\jackson-databind-2.12.4.jar;C:\Users\shuja\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.12.4\jackson-annotations-2.12.4.jar;C:\Users\shuja\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.12.4\jackson-core-2.12.4.jar;C:\Users\shuja\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jdk8\2.12.4\jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.12.4.jar;C:\Users\shuja\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jsr310\2.12.4\jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.12.4.jar;C:\Users\shuja\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\module\jackson-module-parameter-names\2.12.4\jackson-module-parameter-names-2.12.4.jar;C:\Users\shuja\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-tomcat\2.5.3\spring-boot-starter-tomcat-2.5.3.jar;C:\Users\shuja\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-core\9.0.50\tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar;C:\Users\shuja\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-el\9.0.50\tomcat-embed-el-9.0.50.jar;C:\Users\shuja\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-websocket\9.0.50\tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.50.jar;C:\Users\shuja\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-web\5.3.9\spring-web-5.3.9.jar;C:\Users\shuja\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\5.3.9\spring-beans-5.3.9.jar;C:\Users\shuja\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-webmvc\5.3.9\spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar;C:\Users\shuja\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\5.3.9\spring-aop-5.3.9.jar;C:\Users\shuja\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-expression\5.3.9\spring-expression-5.3.9.jar;C:\Users\shuja\.m2\repository\org\thymeleaf\thymeleaf\3.0.12.RELEASE\thymeleaf-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\shuja\.m2\repository\ognl\ognl\3.1.26\ognl-3.1.26.jar;C:\Users\shuja\.m2\repository\org\javassist\javassist\3.20.0-GA\javassist-3.20.0-GA.jar;C:\Users\shuja\.m2\repository\org\attoparser\attoparser\2.0.5.RELEASE\attoparser-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\shuja\.m2\repository\org\unbescape\unbescape\1.1.6.RELEASE\unbescape-1.1.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\shuja\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.32\slf4j-api-1.7.32.jar;C:\Users\shuja\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf\2.5.3\spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf-2.5.3.jar;C:\Users\shuja\.m2\repository\org\thymeleaf\extras\thymeleaf-extras-java8time\3.0.4.RELEASE\thymeleaf-extras-java8time-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\shuja\.m2\repository\org\thymeleaf\thymeleaf-spring5\3.0.12.RELEASE\thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\shuja\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa\2.5.3\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-2.5.3.jar;C:\Users\shuja\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-aop\2.5.3\spring-boot-starter-aop-2.5.3.jar;C:\Users\shuja\.m2\repository\org\aspectj\aspectjweaver\1.9.7\aspectjweaver-1.9.7.jar;C:\Users\shuja\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-jdbc\2.5.3\spring-boot-starter-jdbc-2.5.3.jar;C:\Users\shuja\.m2\repository\com\zaxxer\HikariCP\4.0.3\HikariCP-4.0.3.jar;C:\Users\shuja\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jdbc\5.3.9\spring-jdbc-5.3.9.jar;C:\Users\shuja\.m2\repository\jakarta\transaction\jakarta.transaction-api\1.3.3\jakarta.transaction-api-1.3.3.jar;C:\Users\shuja\.m2\repository\jakarta\persistence\jakarta.persistence-api\2.2.3\jakarta.persistence-api-2.2.3.jar;C:\Users\shuja\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-core\5.4.32.Final\hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar;C:\Users\shuja\.m2\repository\net\bytebuddy\byte-buddy\1.10.22\byte-buddy-1.10.22.jar;C:\Users\shuja\.m2\repository\antlr\antlr\2.7.7\antlr-2.7.7.jar;C:\Users\shuja\.m2\repository\org\jboss\jandex\2.2.3.Final\jandex-2.2.3.Final.jar;C:\Users\shuja\.m2\repository\org\dom4j\dom4j\2.1.3\dom4j-2.1.3.jar;C:\Users\shuja\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\common\hibernate-commons-annotations\5.1.2.Final\hibernate-commons-annotations-5.1.2.Final.jar;C:\Users\shuja\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\jaxb-runtime\2.3.4\jaxb-runtime-2.3.4.jar;C:\Users\shuja\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\txw2\2.3.4\txw2-2.3.4.jar;C:\Users\shuja\.m2\repository\com\sun\istack\istack-commons-runtime\3.0.12\istack-commons-runtime-3.0.12.jar;C:\Users\shuja\.m2\repository\com\sun\activation\jakarta.activation\1.2.2\jakarta.activation-1.2.2.jar;C:\Users\shuja\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-jpa\2.5.3\spring-data-jpa-2.5.3.jar;C:\Users\shuja\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-commons\2.5.3\spring-data-commons-2.5.3.jar;C:\Users\shuja\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-orm\5.3.9\spring-orm-5.3.9.jar;C:\Users\shuja\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-tx\5.3.9\spring-tx-5.3.9.jar;C:\Users\shuja\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aspects\5.3.9\spring-aspects-5.3.9.jar;C:\Users\shuja\.m2\repository\mysql\mysql-connector-java\8.0.26\mysql-connector-java-8.0.26.jar;C:\Users\shuja\.m2\repository\jakarta\xml\bind\jakarta.xml.bind-api\2.3.3\jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.3.jar;C:\Users\shuja\.m2\repository\jakarta\activation\jakarta.activation-api\1.2.2\jakarta.activation-api-1.2.2.jar;C:\Users\shuja\.m2\repository\javax\validation\validation-api\2.0.1.Final\validation-api-2.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\shuja\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\validator\hibernate-validator\6.2.0.Final\hibernate-validator-6.2.0.Final.jar;C:\Users\shuja\.m2\repository\jakarta\validation\jakarta.validation-api\2.0.2\jakarta.validation-api-2.0.2.jar;C:\Users\shuja\.m2\repository\org\jboss\logging\jboss-logging\3.4.2.Final\jboss-logging-3.4.2.Final.jar;C:\Users\shuja\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\classmate\1.5.1\classmate-1.5.1.jar mz.painting.com.Application

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.5.3)

2021-09-07 23:03:00.710  INFO 13304 --- [           main] mz.painting.com.Application              : Starting Application using Java 13.0.1 on DESKTOP-2FIIHFN with PID 13304 (C:\Users\shuja\Desktop\mz\target\classes started by shuja in C:\Users\shuja\Desktop\mz)
2021-09-07 23:03:00.798  INFO 13304 --- [           main] mz.painting.com.Application              : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-09-07 23:03:09.837  INFO 13304 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2021-09-07 23:03:10.394  INFO 13304 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 475 ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfaces.
2021-09-07 23:03:17.773  INFO 13304 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2021-09-07 23:03:17.874  INFO 13304 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2021-09-07 23:03:17.874  INFO 13304 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.50]
2021-09-07 23:03:18.723  INFO 13304 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2021-09-07 23:03:18.723  INFO 13304 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 16400 ms
2021-09-07 23:03:19.900  INFO 13304 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2021-09-07 23:03:20.230  INFO 13304 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.32.Final
2021-09-07 23:03:20.927  INFO 13304 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2021-09-07 23:03:21.830  INFO 13304 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2021-09-07 23:03:26.191  INFO 13304 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2021-09-07 23:03:26.507  INFO 13304 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
2021-09-07 23:03:31.234  INFO 13304 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2021-09-07 23:03:31.296  INFO 13304 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2021-09-07 23:03:33.646  WARN 13304 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2021-09-07 23:03:35.159  INFO 13304 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.w.s.WelcomePageHandlerMapping    : Adding welcome page: class path resource [static/index.html]
2021-09-07 23:03:35.961  WARN 13304 --- [           main] ion$DefaultTemplateResolverConfiguration : Cannot find template location: classpath:/templates/ (please add some templates or check your Thymeleaf configuration)
2021-09-07 23:03:37.067  INFO 13304 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2021-09-07 23:03:37.116  INFO 13304 --- [           main] mz.painting.com.Application              : Started Application in 42.214 seconds (JVM running for 50.262)
2021-09-07 23:04:09.649  INFO 13304 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2021-09-07 23:04:09.649  INFO 13304 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2021-09-07 23:04:09.658  INFO 13304 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 9 ms
User is in Homepage
2021-09-07 23:04:12.849 ERROR 13304 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine             : [THYMELEAF][http-nio-8080-exec-1] Exception processing template "index": Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.SpringInputGeneralFieldTagProcessor' (template: "index" - line 86, col 32)

org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.SpringInputGeneralFieldTagProcessor' (template: "index" - line 86, col 32)
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.java:117) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractElementTagProcessor.process(AbstractElementTagProcessor.java:95) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.util.ProcessorConfigurationUtils$ElementTagProcessorWrapper.process(ProcessorConfigurationUtils.java:633) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.ProcessorTemplateHandler.handleStandaloneElement(ProcessorTemplateHandler.java:918) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.StandaloneElementTag.beHandled(StandaloneElementTag.java:228) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateModel.process(TemplateModel.java:136) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:661) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1098) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1072) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:366) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:190) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1397) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1142) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1081) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:228) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1723) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'user' available as request attribute
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:153) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContext.getBindStatus(RequestContext.java:903) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.context.webmvc.SpringWebMvcThymeleafRequestContext.getBindStatus(SpringWebMvcThymeleafRequestContext.java:227) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.util.FieldUtils.getBindStatusFromParsedExpression(FieldUtils.java:306) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.util.FieldUtils.getBindStatus(FieldUtils.java:253) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.util.FieldUtils.getBindStatus(FieldUtils.java:227) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.AbstractSpringFieldTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractSpringFieldTagProcessor.java:174) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.java:74) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]
    ... 52 common frames omitted
```

Any idea how to fix this ?  thank you

Comment: I rarely use ModelAndView, but shouldn't the return object define both model and view, but you put the "user" object into ModelMap? I would try returing String with the view name instead of ModelAndView. That, or remove the ModelMap parameter and set the model on the ModelAndView return value.

Comment: I have just updated the Controller class as you said and it didn't work either!

Answer (score 1):

At first glance, the `<br>` is missing the closing tag and Thymeleaf processor may complain about it.

It should be
`<input type="text" th:field="*{name}"  placeholder="" /><br />`. Note the ending slash of `<br />`.

You cut out the exception message exactly where it would specify the actual cause, namely after `with root cause [...]`. :)

Comment: I have edited closed the <br/> properly. the line ends with 'with root cause' and the next line comes after that is .. ( Spring with Thymeleaf, BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'user' available as request attribute).    I have just added the Terminal Page

Comment: @WaisShuja Then it could be some redirect to page that hasn't the needed model attribute. It's the same git project as last time? If yes, please mention how to reproduce the problem and I will look into it.

Comment: I found the issue through this comment, thank you @Jamven. I appreciate it a lot